# Is there a way to emulate the 'dynamic workspaces' functionality in Unity?

Tags: unity, workspaces

The one feature of Gnone Shell that I would love in Unity is the 'Dynamic Workspaces'. Is there a way to emulate this functionality within Unity?

I know it can be changed via CCSM, but that method is slow and defeats the purpose of dynamic workspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible. I think everyone agrees that is a very nice feature of Gnome Shell, so I wouldn't be surprised if we get a similar feature in Unity.